# Adding Routes to Rails' Spree E-Commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I just recently upgraded to `1.0.3`, and the routes.rb file in my config/routes folder seems to ignore all my custom routes.

MY routes.rb

```
JollyStore::Application.routes.draw do
  # Mount Spree's routes
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'

  root :to => 'pages#index'

  namespace :admin do
    resources :wysiwygs
  end

  match 'about_us/', :to => "pages#about_us"
  match 'services/', :to => "pages#services"
  match 'raw_resources/', :to => "pages#raw_resources"
  match 'contact_us/', :to => "pages#contact_us"

  match 'privacy_policy/', :to => "pages#privacy_policy"
  match 'return_policy/', :to => "pages#return_policy"
  match 'refund_policy/', :to => "pages#refund_policy"
  match 'cancellation_policy/', :to => "pages#cancellation_policy"
  match 'delivery_shipping_policy/', :to => "pages#delivery_shipping_policy"


end
```

If I run `bundle exec rake routes`, it returns all the approriate routes. But when I try to reach that specific page, I get :

```
undefined local variable or method `about_us_path'
```

Or the same error for every link that is within my custom routes. Somehow my routes are being ignored. Does anyone know a way to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I encountered the same error and found [this solution](http://osdir.com/ml/spree-user/2012-02/msg00043.html), which solved it by prefixing `main_app`, before each of `my_paths/_urls`.  In my case, these were links used in one of the `/override.rb` files.

So, try: `main_app.about_us_path`.

Answer (score 20):

You can add new routes in the Spree using following block in routes.rb file

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
  # Your new routes
end
```

Comment: I found that using `main_app.my_route_path` broke all spree routes unless they were prepended with `spree.`. This solution prevents the need to do that.

Comment: @Zubin Yes, main_app.my_route_path works for accessing main application routes from Spree related controllers/views.

For adding a routes to spree, you can use the solution given by me.

Comment: It seems that prepend method doesn't work any more. Take a look at @Ajay answer

Answer (score 8):

For me prepend did not work.
for me draw did the work:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
   resources :orders, except: [:new, :create, :destroy] do
      post :my_order, on: :collection
   end
end
```