# Spree default url is always orders/populate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree, kaminari, ransack

For some reason default url for 
sort_link is always pointing to /orders/populate?controller=&action=

I want it as whatever default route i have configured on routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if sort_link is a route you defined yourself then try using this
**"main_app.sort_link"** =)

Take a look here from more info
[Adding Routes to Rails' Spree E-Commerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064533/adding-routes-to-rails-spree-e-commerce)