# Issue with path helper for named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm implementing a system for serving static pages in a rails app with the following controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def about
    render 'pages/about'
  end
end
```

I've got the routes set up as follows:

```
get 'about', to: 'pages#about', as: :about
```

I can visit www.example.com/about and it properly renders the about content, but if I try to use the about_path helper with link_to anywhere in my views I get an undefined method error on about_path. Raking my routes returns "about GET /about(.:format)       pages#about"

Anyone have any idea why this helper isn't registering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue caused by integration with Spree. The link below gives two viable solutions.

[Adding Routes to Rails' Spree E-Commerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064533/adding-routes-to-rails-spree-e-commerce)