# Spree custom admin tab helper url on deface override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

I'm building a custom tab on spree 2.1 and I have this on my Deface override which works fine, but when I try to click on my tab being already on this tab it goes to the url /admin/admin/places. So I need this to go always to /admin/places.

Found this https://codeclimate.com/github/spree/spree/Spree::Admin::NavigationHelper and it says that the tab take the first argument and make the path admin_places_path.

```
:insert_after => "[data-hook='admin_tabs']",
:text         => "<%= tab :places, :icon => 'icon-th-large'%>"
```

I tried the usually :url param with 'admin/places' but got the same result and was looking for the tab implementation which led me to the codeclimate and now here. Anyone know how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how I solved:

```
 :text => "<%= tab :places, :icon => 'icon-th-large', url: main_app.admin_places_path %>"
```

Searching for my answer I found that my routes for places were inside my app namespace not in the spree.

```
namespace :admin do
  # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  resources :places
end
```

So, to access the path I had to put "main_app." before the path targeted. See here: [Adding Routes to Rails' Spree E-Commerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064533/adding-routes-to-rails-spree-e-commerce)

Looking the codeclimate code I saw that the url param was set as destination and could use that to put the "main_app." before the path and now is working.

**Edit:**

Found it a better way to do it.

Routes

```
 Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
   namespace :admin do
   # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
   # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
   resources :places
   end
 end
```

Moved all my folders(controllers and views) from controllers/views>places to controllers/views>spree>admin>places

Removed the "my_app." and now it works better and easier.