# Rails decorator method not being called in production, works in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I add the following override for a controller that I inherit from a gem (Spree):

```
module Spree
  module Admin
    UsersController.class_eval do
      def index
        if params[:role].present?
          included_users = Spree::User.joins(:role_users).
              where( spree_role_users: { role_id: params[:role] } ).map(&:id)
          flash[:notice] = "Filtered in #{included_users.count} users"
          @users = @users.where(id: included_users)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, it filters by an additional parameter on the `Admin::UsersController` controller.  The source for that controller in the gem doesn't actually define the `index` method, so mine just gets called instead.

Now, this works perfectly well in development.  However, in production, this method never gets called.

Is there something about `class_eval` that I'm not getting here?  Shouldn't things like this work basically the same in production as they do in development?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the filename for this code? Also, where did you save it in the application directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators are objects that wrap another object. For example they are often used to wrap models with presentational logic.

```
class UserDecorator < SimpleDelegator
  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end

> @user = UserDecorator.new(User.new(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe'))
> @user.full_name
=> "John Doe"
```

This is not a decorator method - you are just reopening the class and adding a method. This is known as [monkey-patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).

Using `class_eval` in this case exactly the same in this as using the class keyword:

```
module Spree
  module Admin
    class UsersController
      def index
        if params[:role].present?
          included_users = Spree::User.joins(:role_users).
              where( spree_role_users: { role_id: params[:role] } ).map(&:id)
          flash[:notice] = "Filtered in #{included_users.count} users"
          @users = @users.where(id: included_users)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With monkey-patches the key is ensuring that your class redefinition is read. I'm guessing the difference between dev and production is due to class catching which prevents the class from being read from `/app` if it has already been defined by the Spree gem. `config/application.rb` uses bundler to require all the gems when the application starts up.

You can assure that a monkey-patch is loaded by placing it in `config/initializers` as all files in that directory are loaded on startup.

But a better alternative to monkeypatching may be to instead subclass the vendor controller and [route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064533/adding-routes-to-rails-spree-e-commerce) to it:

```
class MyUsersController < ::Spree::Admin::UsersController
   def index
     if params[:role].present?
       included_users = Spree::User.joins(:role_users).
         where( spree_role_users: { role_id: params[:role] } ).map(&:id)
       flash[:notice] = "Filtered in #{included_users.count} users"
       @users = @users.where(id: included_users)
    end
  end
end
```

### see also:

- [3 Ways to Monkey-Patch Without Making a Mess](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/)

Comment: Accidentially double posted this answer.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly it.  I actually used to monkey patch from my own folder and a little script to load it at from within the initialiser folder.  However, then I had to restart the app on every edit.  I guess there's a penalty for the convenience.

Comment: Yeah using a subclass is in many ways a cleaner solution and lets you avoid the problems with loading. Modifying vendor code at runtime should really be a last resort.